# Android - Getting InflateException in oppo devices only

Tags: java, android, textview, oppo

I am getting a strange InflateException in my crashlytics. This happens only in Oppo devices with Android version 5.1. From the stack trace, its clear that the issue is with a TextView.
The stack trace is

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class TextView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
   at android.widget.OppoCursorController$FloatPanelViewController.<init>(OppoCursorController.java:1585)
   at android.widget.OppoCursorController.createFloatPanelViewController(OppoCursorController.java:134)
   at android.widget.OppoCursorController$SelectionModifierCursorController.<init>(OppoCursorController.java:518)
   at android.widget.OppoCursorController.create(OppoCursorController.java:81)
   at android.widget.OppoEditor.getOppoSelectionController(OppoEditor.java:417)
   at android.widget.OppoEditor.onTouchEventWrap(OppoEditor.java:322)
   at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8189)
   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8472)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2440)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1748)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2840)
   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2379)
   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8667)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4446)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4234)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3767)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3786)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3913)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3794)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3970)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3767)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3786)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3794)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3767)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6165)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6139)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6110)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6255)
   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:218)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:150)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

And on debugging I assume the problem causing TextView is

```
<TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Title" />
```

I can't find anything wrong in this code.
How can I solve this.?

Comment: This is weird, use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` to see this also causes error on these devices or not.

Comment: @Ruthwik Any update on this question???, Did you find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no @sonu-sanjeev

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ruthwik

Answer (score 0):

I think error in this line

android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"

put @ instead of ?
or try by giving #000 hashcode of color.

and also tell me what is written in xml file line no 42.